# while droppable i try to remove href, because after drop item click event as been enabled

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

```
$(".trash_drop").droppable({
        accept : '.againdrag_drop',
        drop : function(event, ui) {
        var atag = ui.draggable.html();
        var id = $(atag).attr('id');
            $(atag).removeAttr('href');         
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '?AId=ADM_SHORTCUTS_AJAX&del=true&shrt_cut_id='+id,
            data: 'html',
            success: function (data) {
                $(ui.draggable).remove();
            alert($(atag).attr('href')); } });  
            }});
```

I need to prevent click event or else remove attribute href while drag and drop event.

Comment: urbz nailed it on the head. stopPropagation is the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for `event.stopPropagation()`

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/

An alternative could be the `event.preventDefault()` but it wont stop the event from affecting the DOM.

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/